# How to process a list of strings by vowel using LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq, functional-programming

I would like to implement the following algorithm in .NET LINQ (C# preferred):

1. Input is an arbitrary string. The first character of the string is guaranteed to be a vowel. E.g. `"alkjihgefdcb"`
2. Break the string into chunks delimited by vowels. E.g. `"alkj"`, `"ihg"`, `"efdcb"`
3. Sort each chunk alphabetically. E.g. `"ajkl"`, `"ghi"`, `"bcdef"`
4. Join the chunks back together in order to produce an output string. E.g. `"ajklghibcdef"`

Is there an elegant (i.e. purely functional) way to do this? Steps 3 and 4 are easy, but I'm stumped on step 2, which seems to require something that is the opposite of SelectMany. Thanks.

**Edit:** I appreciate the Regex solutions, but I'm looking for a purely LINQ-based approach. In my actual application, the strings are lists of domain objects, so Regex isn't easily applicable.

Comment: Do you mind an extra extension method? If not, check out my answer.

Comment: How do you intend to deal with the fact that `y` can conditionally be a vowel depending on context?  Pretend it always is, pretend if never is, or try to judge based on the context of a non-word?

Answer (score 2):

Sure.

```
Regex.Split(input, @"(?=[aeiou])").Where(s => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s))
     .OrderBy(n => n).Aggregate((a, b) => a + b);
```

If you don't want to use Regex, we'll need an extension method:

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> SplitOn<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, params T[] splitObjs)
{
    //appropriate error checking, check for null etc
    if (!source.Any() || !splitObjs.Any()) return new[]{source};
    List<T> buffer = new List<T>()
    foreach (T item in source)
    {
        if (splitObjs.Contains(item) && buffer.Any())
        {
            yield return buffer;
            buffer.Clear();
        }
        buffer.Add(item);
    }
    if (buffer.Any()) yield return buffer;
}
```

And then it should be as simple as:

```
input.SplitOn('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e').Select(s => new string(s.ToArray()))
     .OrderBy(n => n).Aggregate((a, b) => a + b);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Linq and [Regular Expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc.aspx):

```
string.Join(
    string.Empty, 
    Regex.Matches("alkjihgefdcb", "[aeiou][^aeiou]+")
         .Cast<Match>()
         .Select(m => string.Join(string.Empty, m.Value.OrderBy(c => c))));
// ajklghibcdef
```

Or better yet:

```
string.Join(
    string.Empty, 
    Regex.Split("alkjihgefdcb", "(?=[aeiou])")
         .Select(m => string.Join(string.Empty, m.OrderBy(c => c))));
// ajklghibcdef
```

---

Using pure Linq:

```
var i = 0;
string.Join(
    string.Empty,
    "alkjihgefdcb".GroupBy(c => "aeiou".IndexOf(c) == -1 ? i : ++i)
                  .SelectMany(g => g.OrderBy(c => c)));
// ajklghibcdef
```

Although I hesitate to call that truly *functional* since it relies on `i` being updated by a the side effect of the `GroupBy` method.

Comment: Just out of interest, why the `Skip(1)`?

Comment: because the regex makes a blank, due to matching ahead on a vowel

Comment: @newStackExchangeInstance It always starts with a vowel, so the first string will be empty. I suppose it's not necessary since it will fall out in the final join.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one liner solution using LINQ (Pure Functional way). The idea is to replace all   vowels with `#`  and then split on `#`

```
string input = "alkjihgefdcb";

input = input
 .Replace("a","#a")
 .Replace("e","#e")
 .Replace("i","#i")
 .Replace("o","#u")
 .Replace("u","#u")
 .Split(new char[]{'#'},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
 .Select (i => new string(i.ToCharArray().OrderBy (x => x).ToArray()))
 .Aggregate ((a,b) => a + b);
```

Comment: Sorry! the line .Replace("o","#u") should be .Replace("o","#o) that's a typo.

Comment: The `Aggregate` can just be replaced by a call to `string.Concat` which will be radically more efficient.  The `Aggregate` will create a *lot* of unneeded intermediate strings and spend a lot of time copying the same characters between them.